# Error: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I need help investigating why I'm seeing these errors in the devtools for my registration.html page (screenshots uploaded). I'm not using a frontend framework, and my server is just FiveServer in VsCode.

I'm trying to add a new subscriber using Mailchimp's API, but there's the error starting out I just mentioned. Plus, when I mimic the registration, hit the 'Register' button, it takes me to a 405 page that says "This page isn't working"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DT7w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHYyT.png)

```
    <body>
  <div id="header-container"></div>
  <h2 class="register-headline">Register</h2>
  <h4 class="register-sub-headline">
    Already have an account? <a href="#">Login Here</a>
  </h4>
  <form action="/register" method="post" class="registration-form">
    <label for="first-name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="first-name"
      name="first-name"
      class="form-input"
      required
    /><br /><br />
    <label for="last-name" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="last-name"
      name="last-name"
      class="form-input"
      required
    /><br /><br />
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      id="email"
      name="email"
      class="form-input"
      required
    /><br /><br />
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      id="password"
      name="password"
      class="form-input"
      required
    /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="form-button" />
  </form>
  <script src="registration.js" type="module"></script>
</body>


    const registrationForm = document.querySelector(".registration-form");
// const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");
import * as mailchimp from "/node_modules/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing";

// set mailchimp config
mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "",
  server: "us10",
});

// Mailchimp list ID
const listId = "";

// Function to subscribe new user to Mailchimp
async function subscribeUser(firstName, lastName, email) {
  try {
    const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed", // change to "pending" if confirmation is required
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: firstName,
        LNAME: lastName,
      },
    });

    console.log(`Successfully added new subscriber! Contat's ID is: ${response.id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("There was an error", error);
  }
}

// Add event listener to the form for submission
registrationForm.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submission

  // Get form data
  const formData = new FormData(registrationForm);
  const data = {};
  formData.forEach((value, key) => {
    data[key] = value;
  });

  // Subscribe user to Mailchimp
  subscribeUser(data["first-name"], data["last-name"], data["email"]);

  // Can now send data to server / redirect to Dashboard
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = "../../Pages/Dashboard/dashboard.html";
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting ... those are two separate files: html and JS